# jquery-select2 how to edit the selected value

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

i'm using the [jquery-select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) plugin on select list :

```
$("#product").select2({
    minimumInputLength: 2
});
```

i have a list of products in my select :

- screen 19"
- screen 17"
- screen 15"
- screen 13"

suppose i select 'screen 17"' instead of 'screen 15"' and i want to change it to screen 15" 
so i've to reopen the list and retype all the keyword screen...,
my question : is there any way to edit the selected value directly so i can replace (in this case 17 by 15) instead of retype all the keyword to get the wanted value.

Comment: do you want to problematically change the selected value

Comment: no i want to change it manually

Comment: what do you mean by manually

Comment: do you want the user again key in the value

Comment: i mean instead of the user retype all the keyword (i.e : screen ) to get the list of screens, he will be able to delete 17 -> get the list of all screens -> change his choice

Comment: if your product list is so small why bother have them typing in something. This select2 plugin really seems gear more towards large lists.